# DataTable getting fewer results than Stored Procedure gets

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there a limitation on DataTable where it retrieves fewer than what my stored procedure gets? I'm retrieving 230 via execution of SP, while DataTable only gets 174 from it. Below is my code for executing the SP then adding it to the DT.

The one that sets the strings to SP

```
SqlCommand cmd = DatabaseManager.NewSPCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "salesreport";


foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> valuePair in paramDict)
{
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(valuePair.Key,valuePair.Value);
}
var getData = DatabaseManager.GetData(cmd, out exMsg);
return getData;
```

GetData function

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = GetSQLCommandTimeout();
cmd.Connection = NewConnection();
cmd.Connection.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     da.Fill(dt);
     da.Dispose();
     cmd.Connection.Close();
     cmd.Dispose();
}


return dt;
```

SP in SSMS (withheld other info, retrieves 230 items)

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[salesreport]
        @startDateString = N'03.02.2020',
        @endDateString = N'06.02.2020',
        @locations = N'S69,S90,S91,S93,S94,S95,S96,S97,S98',
        @materials = N''
```

Comment: No - something else is happening

Comment: Need to share specific code including parameters and SP code if you want any assistance.

Comment: Are you sure the 230 rows are retrieved as one result set, or they divided with two result sets as the first returns 56 (230 - 174) rows and the second returns 174 rows?

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader tried executing in SSMS the stored procedure vs the one executed via that function, still 230 vs 174

Comment: Have you verified, by inspecting your parameters while debugging, that you are passing **exactly** the same parameter values to your SP from code?

Comment: A quick guess is that you are passing your dates as datetime parameters and they are getting converted to strings in a different format to the format you are using. Why oh why would you pass a date as a string instead of a date????

Comment: @DaleK, yep code produces 'S69,S90,S91,...' (without spaces), likewise what SP results to. Adding spaces skips that location query. Project was passed on to me where there's a date as string and date as a normal datetime variable in the sql table

Comment: You didn't answer the question with regard to the date parameters, what datatype are the date parameters created in code, and what are their values?

Comment: There must be something different, and as the developer its your job to find it. A SP will always returns the same results for the same inputs (unless its specifically written not to).

Comment: @DaleK it's being sent as string '03.02.2020'. However during SP transaction


    SET @ startDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME,@startDateString,104), 101)

Comment: [`AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) considered harmful. Use a profiler trace to confirm your application is sending the same parameters with the same values. Do *not* use a debugger to inspect these values; this will not tell you what parameter types and values are ultimately sent over the wire.